# Exclude some fields form MongoOperations result

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

My User POJO looks like the following:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I am able to get all document based on the query:

```
List<User> testBedsFromDB = mongoOperations.findAll(User.class);
```

I want to skip some of the fields like `password`. I want to get all the document with `values only in id and username`, `password may be null or empty`. How I can achieve this?

Comment: See [MongoDB Repositories Quries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get all field excluding one field. Code spinet bellow:

```
Query searchQuery = new Query();
searchQuery.fields().exclude("password");
List<User> userList = mongoOperations.find(searchQuery, User.class);
```

With above code `password` field value will be `null`.
You can use multiple exclude like:

```
searchQuery.fields().exclude("username").exclude("password");
```